# How to make for loop displaying 0 if no rows count

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have a for loop for displaying how many tasks completed/not.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < todaytask.Count(t => t.IsChecked == false && t.TaskCreatedBy == taskCreatedBy); i++)
    {            
        if (i == todaytask.Count(t => t.IsChecked == false && t.TaskCreatedBy == taskCreatedBy) - 1)
        {                            
            <MudText style="color:#FF3131;font-size:40px">@i</MudText>
        }
```

It runs perfectly, but when the result is 0 it displays blank instead of 0. How can I display the 0 when it has no rows in the result?

I really appreciate any help that can provide. Thanks

Comment: "when the result is 0", the result of what ?

Comment: When Count is 0, the for loop never runs, because i < 0 will never be true.

Comment: the result of the 'todaytask.Count()'

Comment: Try to read about the [if-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement)

Comment: So how do I fix this @PoulBak ?

Comment: Do you do other things in for loop? If not, then you don't need the loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(todaytask.Count(t => t.IsChecked == false && t.TaskCreatedBy == taskCreatedBy) > 0)
{
  //Your current code
}
else
{
  <MudText style="color:#FF3131;font-size:40px">0</MudText>  
}
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot vote yet. But it works, thanks @Akash!

Answer (score 0):

you can validate if the result is zero and treat the page to show zero, if not zero, you show the variable.